# Changing elements columns in data.frame

Tags: r

this is my dataframe:

```
df<-as.data.frame(matrix(seq(1:20),5,5))
```

What I need to adjust is the column. Basically I need to exclude the first row and then move up all the columns letting the last row with repeated values.

Its sound confusing, probably but the result should be this:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  2  7 12 17  2
2  3  8 13 18  3
3  4  9 14 19  4
4  5 10 15 20  5
5  5 10 15 20  5
```

Actually, I know how to do it but it is not an elegant way.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is `rbind` the dataset by removing the first row, with the last row of the dataset

```
rbind(df[-1, ], df[nrow(df),])
```

Or using index

```
df[c(2:nrow(df), nrow(df)),]
```

Comment: If one wants `rownames` of resulting data.frame to be exactly `1:5`, try `\`rownames<-\`( df[c(2:nrow(df), nrow(df)),], NULL ) `.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example. Though I would like to know what you mean by elegant? Do you mean get a readable code? less lines of code? better performance?

```
library(tidyverse)
df<-as.data.frame(matrix(seq(1:20),5,5)) 
df <- df %>% slice(-1)
df[dim(df)[1] +1,] <- df[dim(df)[1],]
```